# Golang Gorm - incorrect SQL when preloading on nested STI relationship

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I'm getting some weird SQL when preloading a nested relationship on an STI struct:

Firm Struct:

```
type Firm struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirmIdentifier   string
    Name             string
    Type             string
    ClearingMember   *Firm `gorm:"ForeignKey:ClearingMemberID"`
    ClearingMemberID int
    ExecutingFirm    *Firm `gorm:"ForeignKey:ExecutingFirmID"`
    ExecutingFirmID  int
    Address          Address `gorm:"polymorphic:Addressable;"`
    Contacts         []Contact
}

type Execution struct {
    ID                uint
    Price             int
    Side              string
    Symbol            string
    ExecutingFirm     Firm `gorm:"ForeignKey:FirmID"`
    FirmID            int

}
```

Here's the actual data:

```
-
  id:                 1
  name:               Clearing Member 1
  type:               ClearingMember
  clearing_member_id: 

-
  id:                 3
  name:               Executing Firm 1
  type:               ExecutingFirm
  clearing_member_id: 1
-
  # Execution
  id: 1
  side: SELL
  price: 1000
  symbol: FUT.EXC.201612
  firm_id: 3
```

This Query:

```
db.Preload("ExecutingFirm").Preload("ExecutingFirm.ClearingMember").Find(&executions)
```

Generates the below SQL which looks for a Firm with a `clearing_member_id` of 3 as opposed to a Firm with an ID 1:

```
(/home/vagrant/go/src/message_builder_test.go:90) 
[2016-09-15 18:30:33]  [1.14ms]  SELECT * FROM `executions`  

(/home/vagrant/go/src/message_builder_test.go:90)  
[2016-09-15 18:30:33]  [1.51ms]  SELECT * FROM `firms`  WHERE `firms`.deleted_at IS NULL AND ((`id` IN ('3','4')))

(/home/vagrant/go/src/message_builder_test.go:90)  
[2016-09-15 18:30:33]  [1.24ms]  SELECT * FROM `firms`  WHERE `firms`.deleted_at IS NULL AND ((`clearing_member_id` IN ('3','4')))
```

Comment: You're really challenging GORM here. Did you try rewriting it using Custom Preloading SQL?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I was going down that route, but couldn't figure out a way to reference the ids in the anonymous function. Any ideas there?